# Combine more than one \flags in Ruby regex (\A, \w)

Tags: ruby, regex

I try to catch only cases b and d from sample below (ie. `END` should be the only word on a line (or at least be a word not part of  longer word, and END should be at beginning of line (not necessarily ^, could  start from column #2, case \i.)
I cannot combine this all togethernin one regex, can I have more then 1 flag in regex?  I also need this OR in this regex too.
Thanks all. 
M

```
regexDrop = /String01|String2|\AEND/i        #END\n/i
a = "the long END not begin of line"
b = "ENd"              # <@><<  need  this one
c = "END MORE WORDs"
d ="  EnD"            # <@><<  need  this one

if a =~ regexDrop then  puts "a__Match: " + a     else  puts 'a_'     end
if b =~ regexDrop then  puts "b__Match: " + b     else  puts 'b_'     end
if c =~ regexDrop then  puts "c__Match: " + c     else  puts 'c_'     end
if d =~ regexDrop then  puts "d__Match: " + d     else  puts 'd_'     end

##  \w  Matches word characters.
## \A          Matches beginning of string.  (could be not column 1)
```

Comment: Something like `/String01|String2|(^|\t)END\b/` or `/String01|String2|(^|\t)END$/`?

Comment: You can handle _END_ either with `^` or `\A` in this case. It only makes a difference in multi-line mode, where `\A` stays the same but `^` can also mean beginning of string or line. So really `/^[ ]?end\b/i` would work as well. Btw, what is `String01,2` ?

Comment: @sln: In Ruby, `^` and `$` always match start and end of a *line*. [See here](http://batsov.com/articles/2013/12/04/regexp-anchors-in-ruby/). In other words, multiline mode is default in Ruby.

Comment: @stribizhev - Oh yeah, thought I'd seen this before and quickly vowed never to use Ruby. That link has some formatting problems, loses some key characters. In another bizzaro twist, I thought it said `/m` flag means _something_ matches newline (maybe _Dot_, dunno). I shudder to think that if they use in-line modifiers what the outcomes would be. Meanwhile, back to `/\A[ ]?end\b/i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `\A` is an anchor (a kind of a built-in lookehind, or "zero width assertion", that matches the beginning of a whole string. The `\w` is a shorthand class matching letters, digits and an underscore (word characters).

Judging by your description and sample input and expected output, I think you are just looking for `END` anywhere in a string as a whole word and case-insensitive.

You can match the instances with

```
regexDrop = /String01|String2|\bEND\b/i
```

Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/TThjF3)

Output:

```
a__Match: the long END not begin of line
b__Match: ENd
c__Match: END MORE WORDs
d__Match:   EnD
```

Comment: Stibizhev, dlaczego edytować tekst